# Refresh Standard Related List from LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

Is there possibility to refresh the standard related list from LWC, as we can do it using $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire() in aura?

Any alternative to **"$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire() "** in LWC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used getRecordNotifyChange() function to refresh the required list of records, for more info please follow the below:

https://blog.texei.com/refresh-a-record-page-from-a-lightning-web-component-14a5874ff68e

you can also trick it with

```
eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");
```

Comment: I saw this blog, in that it says "getRecordNotifyChange() however can refresh existing Contacts in the related list, but will not bring new Contacts to the page.", so it will not bring new records. I can try with eval one. However, I already used the Lightning message to aura to fire the refreshview.

Comment: Use eval it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Starting Spring 23, you can use [RefreshAPI(Beta)](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lc_refreshview.htm&release=242&type=5). This is currently in BETA but if you have a preview sandbox you can try the below

To refresh it import the module as shown below

```
import { RefreshEvent } from 'lightning/refresh';
```

And to refresh the standard components simply dispatch a Refresh event like below

```
 this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent());
```

Comment: Becoming GA in Summer 23 btw.

Comment: @Mohith It doesn't work when I dispatch the RefreshEvent from an LWC component that is opened by a Screen Quick Action button. Is this a bug or is it working as designed?

Comment: Can you open another question with sample code so I can reach out? Looks like a bug or a feature miss to me..

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Sure, my colleague has posted a new question with the sample code for further discussion: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/410896/refresh-standard-related-list-from-screenaction-lwc-not-working