# Refresh Standard Related List from ScreenAction LWC not working

Tags: lightning-web-components

I tried to use `this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent())` to refresh standard related list on the same page but not working after I close the quick action panel. Below is the sample code

HTML

```
<template>
  <lightning-quick-action-panel header="Edit Fields Action">
    <lightning-record-edit-form
      record-id={recordId}
      object-api-name={objectApiName}
      onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
      <lightning-input-field field-name="Name"></lightning-input-field>
      <lightning-input-field field-name="Phone"></lightning-input-field>
      <lightning-button variant="neutral" label="Cancel"></lightning-button>
      <lightning-button variant="brand" class="slds-m-left_x-small" label="Save" type="submit">
      </lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
  </lightning-quick-action-panel>
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";
import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from "lightning/actions";
import { RefreshEvent } from 'lightning/refresh';

export default class QuickEditFormExample extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId;
  @api objectApiName;

  handleSuccess(e) {
    this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
    this.dispatchEvent(new RefreshEvent());
  }
}
```

meta.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>58.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
            <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
            <objects>
                <object>ObjectName</object>
            </objects>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: stupid question, but does it make a difference to dispatch the events in a different order?

Comment: No difference. I need to refresh new records that I created in the quick action panel. Do you have a better way？