# Can I call notifyRecordUpdateAvailable method in the function called in onsuccess handler of lightning-record-edit-form?

Tags: lightning-web-components, related-list, lightning-recordeditform, refresh, get-record-notify-change

I have a lightning-record-edit-form in which I am editing a record. Once the record is updated successfully, I want to refresh the related lists automatically on the record page.
Can I use notifyRecordUpdateAvailable([{recordId: this.recordId}]) or getRecordNotifyChange([{recordId: this.recordId}]) inside the onsuccess handler function to refresh the related lists. I tried to implement this but did not work for me:

```
handleSuccess() {
    notifyRecordUpdateAvailable([{recordId: this.recordId}]);
    //location.reload();
}
```

I am calling this handleSuccess() method inside onsuccess handler of my lightning-record-edit-form.
I don't want to refresh the entire page by using location.reload().
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Of course, you can call but you don't need `notifyRecordUpdateAvailable` when you are using `lightning-record-edit-form`.

Comment: Thank you for responding, but i need to reload the related lists on the record page once the record is updated, is there any way to achieve this without reloading the entire page?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```js
async handleSuccess(event) {
    let recordId = event.detail.id;
    await notifyRecordUpdateAvailable([{recordId: recordId}]);
    //location.reload();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this code, but it didn't work

Comment: @Celsy are you getting any error?

Comment: it is not throwing any error, I even tried by fetching the ID of the related list record and passed it in await notifyRecordUpdateAvailable([{recordId: this.tprId}]) but still not working

Comment: @Celsy can you share the relevant code? are you sure `tprId` is not null?

Comment: Also, you can try this - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/337280/refresh-standard-related-list-from-lwc